# Graphic is not fitting inside pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Graphics are not fitting inside pictureBox when pictureBox maximized or minimized.

I tried to draw graph on pictureBox using graphics and i made grids and graph coordinates using pen. After running the program, when i tried to maximize / minimize the form graphic inside picture wont fit completely. Even i tried to change properties of pictureBox but it didnt helped.

```
                float cellSizeHeight = pictureBox1.Height / 10F;
                float cellSizeWidth = pictureBox1.Width / 10F;
                Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++)
                {
                    // Vertical
                    g.DrawLine(p, i * cellSizeWidth, 0, i * cellSizeWidth, numOfCells * cellSizeWidth);

                    // Horizontal
                    g.DrawLine(p, 0, i * cellSizeHeight, numOfCells * cellSizeHeight, i * cellSizeHeight);
                }
```

Comment: Show us where this code is? In the Paint event? What is numOfCells? Did you use the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding ?

Comment: 3 errors: You divide by `10` but should divde by `numOfCells`: `float cellSizeHeight = 1f * pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height / numOfCells;` etc.. - Also: The lines are wrong. Use `g.DrawLine(p, i * cellSizeWidth, 0, i * cellSizeWidth, numOfCells * cellSizeHeight); g.DrawLine(p, 0, i * cellSizeHeight, numOfCells * cellSizeWidth, i * cellSizeHeight);`   (width for Xs and Height for Ys !)- Also use `Pens.Green` for simple lines! (No need to dispose of those)

Comment: Does it work now?